# CSS3 -moz-mask support

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, webkit

I'm pretty sure it's not in the specs, but Webkit browsers support *[-webkit-mask](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks)*

Does Firefox have an equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox has [`-moz-mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/mask).

Firefox seems to want a SVG resource.

Comment: +1 Great thanks! Oddly enough I was able to find the -webkit-mask property on MDN but not -moz-mask.

Comment: @Web_Designer: The documentation is sparse, but it hints at that.

Comment: @Web_Designer the 'mask' property is standard in SVG, and doesn't even need the prefix in Gecko.  I fixed the documentation.  Other browsers implement it too, but limit its application to SVG elements for some reason.